Implement WCF service in Python
I have an existing web app developed in ASP.NET Frameword 4.7.2 using C#, and it's very large. Because most NLP libraries (i.e. Spacy) are implemented using Python, I have the idea to define a WCF service interface to be called by the web app, but implement the WCF service in Python so I can use these specialized libraries, and avoid issues calling Python directly from C# or running separate Python process instances. I've been unable to find information on doing so. Or is doing something like using TCP sockets the only way? Any thoughts? Thanks.

You can't find information on it because WCF is a .NET-specific framework. From the [tag:wcf] tag: "Windows Communication Foundation is a part of the .NET Framework [...]"  If your WCF service uses HTTP(S) communication and SOAP serialization (the most likely case), what you have is a SOAP service. In that case, you need to look for how to implement a SOAP service in Python.

Actually, this can't be done. You can try to write Webapi in Python to implement your idea.
